# Geometric pattern quality and filling

Tags: algorithm, statistics, computational-geometry

On the image above there is some geometrical pattern. Model `a` distance is known. Points are not in model distance strictly.

[image]

**I want to:**

- calculate each point quality (real distance between points is not `a`) the better point fits to pattern better quality coeficient it should have (I've tried to take distance and 45deg angle)
- eliminate wrong points (I've marked it with red) - it's connected with pattern quality computing

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Take each point with each other
2. Calculate distance and angle between them
3. Take only points neighbour to current point (which distance is between `a - delta` and `a + delta`
4. Quality is realDistance/modelDistance * realAngle/modelAngle

**Why it failed:**

- Good points quality was strongly decreased with bad points in neighbourhood
- If bad point has only one neighbour and the distance and angle was ok its quality was ok.

**So the question is:** what is the best algorithm to calculate points quality in this case, and fill pattern. Pattern should be filled by averaging position of element taking in account neighbours positions. The best answer will be pseudocode or code or reference to some known algorithm which can be helpful in this case.

Question is a little bit related with my previous question [Filling rectangle with points pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138875/filling-rectangle-with-points-pattern) but the filling could not be done with wrong quality points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error/distortion of the points does not get bigger when you go from left to right or top to bottom (i.e. the average distance `a` between neighbouring good points is known exactly enough), you can try the following:

- bring each point P<sub>i</sub> into the square `[0,a[ x [0,a[` by taking the remainder of x and y coordinates when dividing through a (generating Q<sub>i</sub>). Thus the good points will more or less be mapped onto one point.
- Among these generated points Q<sub>i</sub> choose one point `R` with the closest neighbours (e.g. sum up `1/distance` for all distances to other points Q<sub>j</sub>, j≠ i, and choose the one with maximal sum).
- Now you can distinguish between good and bad points P<sub>i</sub> by looing at the distances Q<sub>i</sub> to R. (Points P<sub>i</sub> whose corresponding Q<sub>i</sub> is close to R will be good points.)

If the point R (with the closest neighbours) has a coordinate close to 0 or a (i.e. R is close to the border of the square `[0,a[ x [0,a[`), you better start from the beginning and add `a/2` to the corresponding coordinate (of each P<sub>i</sub>) before computing the remainder, in order to bring the point R more to the center of the square. (Or you manage to compute the minimal distance of the different possibilities of leaving the square `[0,a[ x [0,a[` on one side and come back into it on the opposite side.)

Comment: But this solution is dependant on some base choosing. Maybe the image I've attached is too specific. What if first points are bad?

Comment: What "base choosing" do you mean? In this approach all points are treated equally, there is nothing like "first points". All points are mapped into the square [0,a[x[0,a[. Those that come close together in this square are the "good" ones. Problems will only arise if the average distance `a` between the good points is not exactly enough known.

Comment: Could you clarify last paragraph of your answer (from "If the point R..."). What with second part of the question the pattern filling?

Comment: If you try the algorithm and look at the Q<sub>i</sub> you will understand the problem that arises, when R is close to the border of the square. The dense cloud of Q<sub>i</sub>-s originating from good P<sub>i</sub>-s can be split (accross opposite borders). Sorry, but the rest you will have to check out yourself. I can only offer a completely different approach (see next answer).

Comment: Ok I understand the problem of spliting now. Will implement this and try how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The good points seem to be aligned along a grid. The grid lines can be found using a line fitting algorithm using [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC). RANSAC line fitting is a probabilistic algorithm. You will have to repeat it until you find a line that is almost horizontal or vertical. Take the points on/near this line out and go for the next grid line. Depending on your problem characteristics you will stop looking for new grid lines if too few points are left or too few points are on/near one line. The remaining points are the bad ones. When you take the intersections of the found grid lines and there is no point (from all the original ones) near the intersection, then you can fill in a point here.